# static class constants vs namespace of constants

Tags: c++

Imagine you want to instanciate "special" cases with a common name of a class. Let's take as an example the class Color, defined below:

```
struct Color {
    float r, g, b;
    constexpr Color(float r, float g, float b) : r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
};
```

And imagine we want define in some organized way constants such as "RED", "BLUE", etc. I came across with this two ways of defining them:

1) As static constants inside the Color class, such as `Color::RED`, `Color::GREEN`

2) Inside a namespace named as the plural of the class:

```
namespace Colors{
    constexpr Color RED(1, 0, 0);
    /* ETC */
}
```

So they are accessed as `Colors::RED` `Colors::BLUE`...

I find the second one easier to maintain, as it only needs one definition per element, whilst the first one needs two declarations, one inside and another outside the class. However I'm not sure of its correctness.

In short: I'm asking about whether if the second one is a correct way of doing it or if I should go with the first one or any other alternative. I'm not referring to if it compiles, it does. I'm talking about good design practices.

Comment: why do you think there is a problem with correctness? We cannot disprove that unless you tell us what is your assumption

Comment: i feel doing it the second way (namespace) is better and easy to maintain

Comment: Some documentation tools, like doxygen will fail to group your namespace objects with the relevant class.

Comment: @artcorpse That's not a failure; that's expected behaviour. Why should they be grouped with the class? The namespace _is_ a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely up to you.

Personally I don't want to have to change the class definition whenever I add a new "preset". So, unless the class's implementation itself needs those constants, I'd keep them out of it.

However, you can't pass namespaces as template arguments so sometimes (in much more complicated scenarios) you're "stuck" with a class. Still, that doesn't have to be the class `Color`.

---

> the first one needs two declarations, one inside and another outside the class

As of C++17, that's no longer true; [we have `inline`](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2205/7-features-of-c17-that-will-simplify-your-code/inline-variables).

Comment: You cannot inline a instance of a class inside itself, it won't compile. You can inline it in an outside re-declaration. However it also needs two declarations of the same preset, so it turns out that it has no advantage over the solution #1

Comment: @oierlauzi Okay, that's true :)